# Slashcommand in Discord selfbot not working after recent update

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

Below code basically is a selfbot sending "remind" slashcommand. The id is id of the bot and the remind is name of the command. It workes perfectly fine, but (probably) after this new update it doesnt't work.

```js
// ...

const channel = await client.channels.fetch(process.env.remind_channel)

await channel.sendSlash('499595256270936326', 'remind')
console.count('reminded!') // first remind

setInterval(async function () {
  await channel.sendSlash("499595256270936326", "remind");
  console.count("reminded!");
}, 1000000);

// ...
```

I tried checking the id of the bot as well as the command name and they are both correct. This is the error I am facing:

```bash
Error [INTERACTION_SEND_FAILURE]: SlashCommand remind is not found (With search)
Debug:
 + botId: 499595256270936326 (ApplicationId: 499595256270936326)
 + args: null
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_SEND_FAILURE'
```